# Blazor server appsettings files

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-server-side, appsettings

The Blazor server web site is developed on Windows. The target for publishing is Linux.

After compiling (release) and publishing the release version of the Blazor Server project with MS VS 2019, the publish folder contains (among other files):

> appsettings.Development.json

> appsettings.json

> appsettings.production.json

I wonder, why there is the file appsettings.Development.json. After making a Release build, I would expect having only one *.json file.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **JSON Configuration Provider** used in the *Configuration* process on ASP.NET Core is different to the **Transformation provider** used by *web.config* files.

The *Configuration* works with a **chain** process and the json files are under *your* control.

Look at this piece of code:

```
config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
  .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", 
  optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
```

The configuration provider via the *JSON Provider* does not apply any transformation for you.

### Infos

More information from official Microsoft doc page:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Generally speaking in Visual Studio the system environment variable ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT, during debug session, is set to **Development** , by default in production is set to **Production**.

Comment: thanks for reply. If I have a running web site, how can I know in which mode is it currently running?

Comment: Update in my answer.